# How to give a CSS class via XML?

Tags: magento2, css, xml

There is a link in header portion called quick order, I need to add css class for that link but there is no phtml file for that link so I need to add it via xml. Below is the xml file from vendor.

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="b2blinks" before="top.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\QuickOrder\Block\Link" name="quick_order_link" ifconfig="btob/website_configuration/quickorder_active" after="-"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

How can give css class for quick order link?

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

***Note: Space not allow into css_class value.***

> **You can also add class using container**

```
<container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links">
    <-- Add your block here -->
</container>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: I have tried but not working. Can you please explain a little bit? I need to give css class for this block, <block class="Magento\QuickOrder\Block\Link" name="quick_order_link" ifconfig="btob/website_configuration/quickorder_active" after="-"/>

Comment: use this into your argument <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>And before check please run upgrade command.

Answer (score 0):

> you can add your custom class for your custom link like this

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="b2blinks" before="top.links">
      <arguments>
         <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument> // like this
      </arguments>
   <block class="Magento\QuickOrder\Block\Link" name="quick_order_link" ifconfig="btob/website_configuration/quickorder_active" after="-"/>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Tried the same way but not working

Comment: I have to give the css class name for this block, <block class="Magento\QuickOrder\Block\Link" name="quick_order_link" ifconfig="btob/website_configuration/quickorder_active" after="-"/>

Comment: please try it, <block class="Magento\QuickOrder\Block\Link"  name="quick_order_link" htmlClass="your customclass"  ifconfig="btob/website_configuration/quickorder_active" after="-"/>

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this with XML, if you look at the block XML instructions on the [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_block) you'll see there is no method for adding CSS classes.

This means it would only be possible if the PHP class contains the functionality, from a quick search through the PHP this is not the case.

You will need to either wrap your block in a `container` element with the `htmlClass` attribute or use a new block.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean this? I've given css in xml header for my custom modules.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/cssfilename.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="editor"/>
   
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="index_edit_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

css file location "web/css/"

Comment: and even for blocks, the css files could be added the same way as mentioned above.